# how to store values of foreach as array

Tags: php

```
<?php 
  $samgri = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_puja_order($param1,$param);

  foreach ($samgri as $row){
    $puja_samagri = $row['puja_samagri'];
  }
  $puja_sam = explode(',', $puja_samagri);

  foreach ($puja_sam as $samagri_id){
    $samg  = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_id($samagri_id);
  }

  if(sizeof($samg) == 0){
    echo '<h5 style = "text-align:center">No samagari available</h5>';
  }else{
    foreach ($samg as $row){


?>
```

but it was fetching only the last record not total records

Comment: Seems your code is not completed. Please do complete first!

Comment: When a user receives a good answer to his or her question, that user has the option to "accept" an answer. Acceptance is indicated by a colored checkmark next to the answer that has been accepted by the original author of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should add brackets after the array name like:

```js
<?php 
$samgri = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_puja_order($param1,$param);

//Declare the arrays
$puja_samagri = new array();
$samg = new array();

foreach ($samgri as $row){

$puja_samagri[] = $row['puja_samagri'];

}

$puja_sam     = explode(',', $puja_samagri);

foreach ($puja_sam as $samagri_id){

$samg[]  = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_id($samagri_id);
}

if(sizeof($samg) == 0){

echo '<h5 style = "text-align:center">No samagari available</h5>';

}else{

foreach ($samg as $row){


?>
```

It will use the automatic int position (from 0 going up untill you have all the results). Also it might be a good idea to declare them as arrays before using them.

Comment: Dont worry pal i upvoted new guys thanking with the comment which is not as per stack overflow the green button click it self is a thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to take array after every foreach veriable as like follows :

```
<?php 
$samgri = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_puja_order($param1,$param);

foreach ($samgri as $row){

$puja_samagri[] = $row['puja_samagri'];

}

$puja_sam     = explode(',', $puja_samagri);

foreach ($puja_sam as $samagri_id){

$samg[]  = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_id($samagri_id);
}

if(sizeof($samg) == 0){

echo '<h5 style = "text-align:center">No samagari available</h5>';

}else{

foreach ($samg as $row){


?>
```

Hope this will help you :)