# only one record is getting fetched not all why?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
    <?php 
    $samgri = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_puja_order($param1,$param);

    foreach ($samgri as $row){

    $puja_samagri = $row['puja_samagri'];

    }

    $puja_sam     = explode(',', $puja_samagri);

    foreach ($puja_sam as $samagri_id){

    $samg = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_id($samagri_id);
    }

    foreach ($samg as $row){


    ?>
    <html>

                        <form action = '<?php echo site_url();?>/main/pdfdownload'>
                        <div class="panel panel-default">




                            <div class="panel-body">


                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                    <table id="customers2" class="table table-bordered datatable">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                                <th>S.NO</th>
                                                <th>Items</th>
                                                <th>Quantity</th>
                                                <th>Price</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody>
                                        <?php $i = 1; ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td><?php echo $i; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['quantity']; ?></td>
                                                <td><?php echo $row['price']; ?></td>
                                            </tr>

                                        <?php  
                                        $i++; 
        }

?>

                                        </tbody>

                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div style = 'text-align:right'>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Download</button>
                    </div>
                        </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, Sai. Before asking for a new question, can you please mark as answered [previous question(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35864663/how-to-store-values-of-foreach-as-array)? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first print the `$samgri` variable and check what result you getting. If your `$samgri` contain array of result then change your code with below code.

```
<?php 
        $samgri = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_puja_order($param1,$param);
        $puja_samagri = [];
        foreach ($samgri as $row){

        $puja_samagri[] = $row['puja_samagri'];

        }    
        if(!empty($puja_samagri))
        {
            foreach ($puja_samagri as $samagri_id){

            $samg = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_id($samagri_id);
            }

            foreach ($samg as $row){
        }

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$samgri = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_puja_order($param1,$param);

foreach ($samgri as $row){

$puja_samagri = $row['puja_samagri'];

}
```

Now print_r($puja_samagri);die; // Add and see it is a single record only

**So use array instaed of that in foreach** i.e. = $puja_samagri[]

```
$puja_sam     = explode(',', $puja_samagri);

foreach ($puja_sam as $samagri_id){

$samg = $this->crud_model->get_puja_samagri_by_id($samagri_id);
}

foreach ($samg as $row){


?>
```

**NOTE:** Do the same thing in other foreach just define array otherwise it will contain the last value only...

Answer (score 0):

You Should fetch Array As result as mentioned in [Codeigniter User Guide](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR QUERY");

 foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
 echo $row['title'];
 echo $row['name'];
 echo $row['body'];
}
```